# IIS /.Net Allow 1 Public IP to access the website exclusively

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, firewall, iis-7.5, windows-firewall

How can I grant exclusive access to my client to a website hosted at my IIS Server? Which Firewall rule shall I add his public ip?

IIS: Version 7.5.7600
Server: WS2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Exact steps depend on a firewall you use. In general:

- Rule type: inbound, allow
- Local port: IIS port (most probably 80)
- Remote IP: your client's public IP (they should have a static IP)